# Reliably using motor at higher than normal voltage

Tags: voltage

I am making an ROV that uses Jameco DC Motors, and I use a 12 volt battery. I looked at the spec sheet for the motor, and found that the normal voltage to run these motors are 12v, but the operating range is from 6-18 volts. Does this mean I could use a boost converter to take my 12v battery, and set it to 18v, making the motors go reliably faster? I am not trying to blow up the motors, but I do want to make them faster if possible. I'm new to experimenting with these types of things, so sorry if this is a silly question or if it has been already answered (didn't know what to look up!). Thanks

jameco 232022
website: https://www.jameco.com/z/MS5N-1885-R-12-Volt-DC-Motor-740mA-9820-RPM_232022.html

Comment: i did search that up! but since the spec sheet lists an operating range of 6v to 18v i was curious if 18v would be a safe voltage then.

Comment: is the motor worth a couple of dollars? ... if it is, run one at 20V and see how long it takes to fail.

Comment: @jsotola good point! added. but i do think that i will have to resort to that method anyways. thank you for your input thus far!

Comment: the graph shows the highest efficiency at ~9.2V and highest power output at 14V

Comment: Before you go doing anything you need to figure out if the motor is slow because it is already over-loaded. If your load torque is already straining the motor, upping the voltage will just kill it faster. If that is the case, you need a bigger motor or possibly a different gear ratio.

Answer (score 0):

If the data sheet says 18v, then you can be assured that if you apply 18v, the motor will spin fast, faster than at 12v, and won't fall part or burn in that short test.

A brushed motor's brushes and commutator will wear at a rate dependent on the voltage and the operating current of the motor. These both determine how much energy is deposited in the sparks that occur at the commutator, and erode it. The size of the sparks is also determined by the commutation timing, that is the angle that the commutator electrical axis makes to the field magnetic axis. This angle is usually adjusted to be optimum at the rated voltage, and for the designed direction of rotation.

You can assume the motor will wear faster at 18v than at 12v. It will not be (18/12) times faster, I doubt it would even be as low as (18/12)^3 times faster, but raised to some much higher power. That will be acceptable in some performance applications, and not acceptable in hi-rel applications. You must determine either by experiment, or by getting more detailed specs from the vendor, what the lifetime will be under your operating conditions, to see whether it's acceptable to you.

Note that BLDC motors do not have brushes. If you want reliable operation, then it might be worthwhile looking at these.